# Mesh axis wrong

Tags: transforms

Wanted to move mesh on X axis, but the X axis is diagonal for some reason.[image]

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Maybe you switched to the "wrong" **[transform orientation](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/3dview/object/editing/transform/control/orientations.html#transform-orientations)**

Comment: .. to expand..  if you mean you want to translate along the local X of the object, select 'Local' as the transform orientation, hit 'G' 'X' and 'X' **again**. The first X gives you global X, the second X gives you the X of the selected transform orientation.

Comment: Yeah that does not work for some reason.